# Vega-Lite: Adding custom legends not based on the field value/auto color/auto shape

Tags: plot, graph, legend, vega-lite, vega

I'm looking for a way to output custom legends for multi-field data. Ideally, I'd like to statically color-code all the fields I may have (in total there might be about 20), and output legends per color and arbitrary text, or at least a field name.

In the example below, I'd like a legend to show "`blue stroke` Series 1 `red stroke` Series 2".

I'd be happy to show what I have at the moment, but I have tried placing "legend" seemingly everywhere it may fit, and it doesn't do anything.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 1, "y": 10},
      {"x": 2, "y": 7},
      {"x2": 1, "y2": 11},
      {"x2": 2, "y2": 12}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {"x": {"type": "quantitative"}, 
               "y": {"type": "quantitative"}},
  "layer": [
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": "line",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "x"}, 
            "y": {"field": "y"},
            "color": {"value": "blue"}
            
            }
        },
        {
          "mark": "line",
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field": "x2"},
            "y": {"field": "y2"},
            "color": {"value": "red"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legends in Vega-Lite are created from encodings, so if you want a legend to be shown you need to construct an appropriate encoding. For layered charts, one way to do this is using a `datum` encoding for each layer, and then you can construct a custom color scale mapping these encodings to the desired color. For example ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoAB5oAjEoCeFgAwBfBabQAma2gDsj0y4vXfqObm3iAmAW4gVgHmLvYAuo4gcLJQbMo0smRozpogmFY4cGggAI4MSLKYdGo0pCCJNrn5hcVlFVXqVXWJqYJsAE7ZeQVF6LJsCBk6iiDQOqOgyhNIGUYgAMpw-TT65jOb2-q+cUr9FWSjhiBMukWncMogCfaJgkhWW0agyP0A1sXCWR3JIpNIZLK5My5ABmO0Ej3QZgaQ1hcHhxRsPTYfUGuVUmAYCGKBx2ED2LxCP3+6EBwOSqXSmSGUNAqPRiN8yJhcIRkU5Sl6AyG+MJxK2pM5LwSQA)):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"x": 1, "y": 10},
      {"x": 2, "y": 7},
      {"x2": 1, "y2": 11},
      {"x2": 2, "y2": 12}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {
      "type": "nominal",
      "scale": {"domain": ["Series1", "Series2"], "range": ["blue", "red"]}
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x"},
        "y": {"field": "y"},
        "color": {"datum": "Series1"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x2"},
        "y": {"field": "y2"},
        "color": {"datum": "Series2"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you a ton for the explanation!

Comment: Sir, you seem to be well-versed in internal Vega-lite entities. Could you suggest good reading for beginners like myself? Docs and examples are not very helpful in building this mental model of entities relations (channels, markrefs and other terms used throughout the docs).

Comment: No, I don't know of any resource like that beyond the docs, unfortunately